# C# mongo upsert json

Tags: c#, mongodb

I has the following json record:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a0152e21b4af42540d8e492"),
  "Country" : "MY",
  "Staff_ID" : "NBJ64",
  "WeCare" : {
      "CustSatisfaction" : [ 
          {
            "Trans_Year" : 2017,
            "Trans_Month" : 4,
            "HH" : 1,
            "HN" : 0,
            "NH" : 0,
            "NN" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "Trans_Year" : 2017,
            "Trans_Month" : 1,
            "HH" : 1,
            "HN" : 0,
            "NH" : 0,
            "NN" : 0
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

How can I write in C# to upsert the records if not exists? I trying to make the upsert function dynamic, so the field may vary and there will be no strongly typed class declared. Is there any possibility to upsert json directly into mongoDB?

Comment: What do you think you mean by "upsert"? Which part is supposed to "exist"? Is it the fields like `"Country"` and `"Staff_ID"`? Or is it about adding new items to `"CustSatisfaction"`?

Comment: What I need is to check the entire json whether exists in mongodb. If not exists, then will insert it or else it update the records. I am not sure whether it can be done.

Comment: What you are saying does not make any sense. An "upsert" is where there is something what "uniquely" identifies a document. If that "unique key" is matched then you "update" the document, and when it is not matched you "insert" a new document. Something in your data must "uniquely" identify it. What is that? Don't be confused with "replacing", because that is a separate thing and entirely possible, once the "unique" document is identified.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. You are right, Country and Staff_ID is the fields suppose to exists and "CustSatisfaction" is the one I need to check.